# How to do Luhn check in df column in Spark Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, luhn

df has one string column like "100256437". I want to add one more column to check whether it would pass Luhn. If pass, lit(true), else lit(false).

```scala
  def Mod10(c: Column): Column = {
    var (odd, sum) = (true, 0)
 
    for (int <- c.reverse.map { _.toString.toShort }) {
      println(int)
      if (odd) sum += int
      else sum += (int * 2 % 10) + (int / 5)
      odd = !odd
    }
    lit(sum % 10 === 0)
  }
```

Error:

```
error: value reverse is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column
    for (int <- c.reverse.map { _.toString.toShort }) {
                  ^
error: value === is not a member of Int
    lit(sum % 10 === 0)
                 ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, you are dealing with Spark Dataframes.

Lets say you have this dataframe

```
val df = List("100256437", "79927398713").toDF()

df.show()
```

```
+-----------+
|      value|
+-----------+
|  100256437|
|79927398713|
+-----------+
```

Now, you can implement this Luhn test as an UDF,

```
val isValidLuhn = udf { (s: String) =>
  val array = s.toCharArray.map(_.toString.toInt)

  val len = array.length

  var i = 1
  while (i < len) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      var updated = array(len - i) * 2
      while (updated > 9) {
        updated = updated.toString.toCharArray.map(_.toString.toInt).sum
      }
      array(len - i) = updated
    }
    i = i + 1
  }

  val sum = array.sum

  println(array.toList)

  (sum % 10) == 0
}
```

Which can be used as,

```scala
val dfWithLuhnCheck = df.withColumn("isValidLuhn", isValidLuhn(col("value")))

dfWithLuhnCheck.show()
```

```
+-----------+-----------+
|      value|isValidLuhn|
+-----------+-----------+
|  100256437|       true|
|79927398713|       true|
+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Spark 3.5+** has [`luhn_check`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#luhn_check)

```scala
expr("luhn_check(value)")
```

Full example:

```scala
val df = List("8112189876", "79927398714").toDF()

val df2 = df.withColumn("luhn_valid", expr("luhn_check(value)"))
df2.show()
// +-----------+----------+
// |      value|luhn_valid|
// +-----------+----------+
// | 8112189876|      true|
// |79927398714|     false|
// +-----------+----------+
```